# Why my delete post function doesn't work?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I was trying to make a simple blog application using Rails. I added a function like "creating a new post", "edit a post" I wanted also to add a delete function. But it doesn't work. Please help me!

Here is my "posts_controller.rb" file

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new 
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post 
    else 
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show 
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit 
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end 

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :body))
      redirect_to @post
    else 
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to post_path
  end

  private 
    def post_params 
     params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
    end
  end
```

"show_html.erb" file:

```
<div id="post_content">
  <h1 class="title">
    <%= @post.title %>
  </h1>

  <p class="date">
    Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> Ago
      | <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %>
      | <%= link_to 'Delete', post_path(@post), method: :delete,
                    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  </p>

  <p class="body">
    <%= @post.body %>
  </p>
</div>
```

And it gave me this error: 
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#show
Couldn't find Post with 'id'=7
Extracted source (around line #22):

```
def show 
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: The request is being sent as GET due to a javascript error. Rails relies on `jquery-ujs` to send non-GET method requests from links. Check the browser console for errors. You can also use `<%= button_to 'Delete', @post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>` which does not rely on JS.

Comment: This question comes up every day but I can't find a good duplicate target. Any ideas?

Comment: ok. thank you very much. i will try the button solution and i will write you if doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `destroy` method, you're redirecting to the `show` route for the `post` you just deleted. That's why your getting the `RecordNotFound` error.

Change `redirect_to post_path` to `redirect_to posts_path` in your `destroy` method and see if that clears up this error.